# QRegExp to parse only string starting with a specific character

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I am trying to parse these strings using regexp but i think my regexp statement is incorrect.

I am given a string and whenever it has a newline and carriage return, they must be separated in two strings. The strings has this following format

```
[CharSize][Inverted][Aligned]Data
```

For example if I am given data like this

```
QString s1 = "[6][1][0]Data1\n\r[5][0][1]Data2";
```

When I separate them there would be two QString and I will take the data inside the open and closed brackets.

Another valid data is like this:

```
QString s2 = "[7][0][1]Data3"
```

Invalid data is like this:

```
QString s3 = "abc[8][1][1]Data4"
```

I applied the following QRegExp below:

```
QRegExp clrf("\n\r|\r\n|\n");
QStringList sp = str.split(clrf);
```

QRegexp clrf works fine for separating data with newline and carriage return, reversed or just newline. Note: s1, s2 and s3 are processed fine here.

The problem is here:

```
QRegExp value("[^a-z]?\\[([0-9a-z]+)\\]\\[([0-9a-z]+)\\]\\[([0-9a-z]+)\\]([A-Za-z0-9\\'\\ \"]*)");
```

When I use the above code, s1, s2 and s3 are all processed. S3 **SHOULD NOT** be processed since its first character is not the open bracket. Can you help me correct my QRegExp?

Thank you.

EDIT:
Entire Code:

```
void parseString(QString str)
{

    QRegExp clrf("\n\r|\r\n|\n");
    QRegExp value("\\[([0-9a-z]+)\\]\\[([0-9a-z]+)\\]\\[([0-9a-z]+)\\]([A-Za-z0-9\\'\\ \"]*)");
//     QRegExp value("^\[(\\d+)\]\[(\\d+)\]\[(\\d+)\](.*)$");

    int p = 0, i = 0;
    int res;
    int cs = 0, inv = 0, al = 0;

    QStringList sp = str.split(clrf);

    XLineString ls;

    for (i = 0; i < sp.size(); ++i) {
        res = value.indexIn(sp[i], p);
        while (res != -1) {
            printf("Text=[%s]\n", value.cap(EData).toStdString().c_str());

            printf("Digit cs[%d] ", value.cap(ECharSize).toInt());
            printf("inv[%d] ", value.cap(EInvert).toInt());
            printf("al[%d]\n", value.cap(EAlignment).toInt());

            cs = value.cap(ECharSize).toInt();
            if (value.cap(EInvert).toInt())
                inv = 1;
            else
                inv = 0;

            if (value.cap(EAlignment).toInt())
                al = 1;
            else
                al = 0;
            ls.addLine(value.cap(EData).toStdString().c_str(), cs, inv, al);
            p += value.matchedLength();
            res = value.indexIn(str, p);
        }
    }    
}

int main()
{   
    QString str1[] = { 
        "[12][0][0]DATA1\n\r[78][0][1]DATA2",
        "abc[1][1][1]THIS SHOULD NOT PASS",
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(str1) / sizeof(str1[0]); ++i)
        parseString(str1[i]);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reason to explicitly need to specify: [^a-z]?, why not just use start of string: "^\[[0-9]+\]...'  Finally I think your expression can be quite simplified with \w and \d: `'^\\[(\\d+)\\]\\[(\\d+)\\]\\[(\\d+)\\](.*)$'`

Comment: I used `[^a-z]?` which is supposedly to neglect any strings having characters starting with non open bracket. 

You mean this? `^\\[([0-9a-z]+)\\]....` I tried this one but s3 is still being caught.

I am really sorry. I am not good in regexp. Can you explain your suggested expression on the last part?

Comment: Btw, I just tried `QRegExp value("^\\[(\\d+)\\]\\[(\\d+)\\]\\[(\\d+)\\](.*)$");` and still s3 is being caught :(

Comment: What are you using for the matching itself? The regex is correct, it's something else.

Comment: I displayed above my entire code. Sorry for the trouble I caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question I've tested this out with PyQt5 (for simplicity)

```
import re
R = ["\\[([0-9a-z]+)\\]\\[([0-9a-z]+)\\]\\[([0-9a-z]+)\\]([A-Za-z0-9\\'\\ \"]*)", "^\[(\\d+)\]\[(\\d+)\]\[(\\d+)\](.*)$"]
tests = ["[6][1][0]Data1\n\r[5][0][1]Data2", "[7][0][1]Data3", "abc[8][1][1]Data4"]
s = re.compile("\n\r|\r\n|\n") # emulate QRegExp split feature
for r in R:
    r=QRegExp(r)
    for T in tests:
        for t in s.split(T):
            print(r.indexIn(t))
```

The results:

```
0
0
0
3
0
0
0
-1
```

Conclusion: Your original match can also work if you simply test that "indexIn" is equal to 0 rather than not equal to -1, while my modified version should work either way.

I think your best bet is simply to modify your code making sure the index is equal to 0. I might also suggest that you use an If statement rather than a While statement, or you may repeatedly match the same line.

Comment: my bad, I didn't check every block of my code -_- Thanks a lot u8sand :)